Create SQL function using Django migrations command
I am using Django Framework in Python with MySQL Database
For adding a table in the database, I create a class in models.py and then run
python manage.py makemigrations. This creates the migration file in my app with the table columns details.
Now, similarly, I want to create a new function in my database.
For now, I create a new empty migration file in my app using
python manage.py makemigrations --empty myApp
and then add the SQL code to the migration file
operations[
    migrations.RunSQL('Create function SQL Code')
]

This editing migration file can be done on a local or testing environment but is not advisable in the production environment. Is there any better way to create the MySQL function through Django Migrations command or models.py that works similarly to tables and creates functions only 1 time when we use the migrate command?

"This editing migration file can be done on a local or testing environment but is not advisable in the production environment" why? Creating custom migrations is a pretty established thing and I don't see any reason for it to be avoided for production environments. This is pretty much the way you are supposed to do it.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for the reply. But what if I have multiple servers, so won't it become a manual procedure to create custom migrations and edit the file on each of these servers?

Are you not committing your migrations to version control?... See: Should I be adding the Django migration files in the .gitignore file?

If you have multiple servers and aren't committing your migrations forget custom migrations you're simply going to have issues with the migration system itself.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for the reference link. We as a team were facing a lot of conflicts while committing migrations to version control, so recently we added that in git ignore and thus these custom migrations issues arouse.
